# ¿Como cambiar el icono de una pestaña en ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Buen día, quisiera saber donde puedo quitar ese icono que da por default la pagina de ASP.NET, le quiero poner otro. AYUDA!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la parte superior de tu código HTML (Dentro del tag `<HEAD>`) debes colocar una etiqueta con el nombre por defecto de tu imagen llamado favicon

el tag completo debe verse así.

```
<link rel=”shortcut icon” type=”image/png” href=”/favicon.png”/>
```

Evidentemente, la dirección del ícono debe estar acorde a tu código.

Si te sirve la respuesta, no te olvides de marcarla como correcta.

Y ante cualquier duda, consulta.

Comment: muchas gracias, si funciono

Comment: Para eso estamos!